# How can I display article meta description using Twig template syntax?

Tags: php, twig

I am trying to replace the post excerpt blurb (eg. `{{Post.PostBody|striptags|truncate(550)|raw}}` ) for lead story on this page - http://renters.apartments.com/ - with the post's meta description.

I can't, however, figure out what I need to use to replace this `Post.PostBody` syntax:

```
<div class='post.body'>
    {{Post.PostBody|striptags|truncate(550)|raw}} 
    <strong><a href="{{Post.PostUrl}}">Read more &rarr;</a></strong>
</div>
```

Sorry for remedial question, but I don't have any PHP/Twig experience so am a bit stuck, if anyone can help.

Comment: ok, step 1: learn how to format SO questions. step 2: read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. step 3: edit your question. also consider reading the Twig docs first, it's in there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this in your `<head>`?

```
{% if Post.PostMetaDescription %}
    <meta name="description" content="{{Post.PostMetaDescription}}">
{% else %}
    <meta name="description" content="{{Post.PostBody|striptags|truncate(550)|raw}}">
{% endif %}
```

This way it will only replace the `PostBody` if `PostMetaDescription` has a value.